# How long does it take to receive payouts on Minergate?

Tags: ether, mining

I've been mining ETH on [Minergate](https://minergate.com) for about 4hrs but I can't see anything adding up to my balance.

I have an NVidia GTX1070 producing an average of 27Mh/s.
Any idea if not seeing anything after a few hours is normal or there is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read up on how [Minergate](https://minergate.com) works, I've noticed that they've [two payment models](https://minergate.com/faq/difference-between-pps-and-pplns). 
They are **PPS** (Pay Per Share) and **PPLNS** (Pay Per Last N Shares).

Do you know which one you have selected?

You'll need to in order to have an idea of how often you're going be receive payouts. I've read that people have gotten payouts quite regularly then it stops all of a sudden. Completely dependant on your selected payment model. For example, PPLNS will give you wide fluctuations in your 24 hour payout, but for hardcore miners,the law of large numbers states you will earn more this way.

---

> Any idea if not seeing anything after few hours is normal or there is something wrong?

You may have a corrupted DAG file. You'll know if you've suddenly been receiving only '*bad*' shares. If this is true, then delete your DAG file and restart the miner:

Path on Windows machine: *C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\minergate.ethash-minergate*

Comment: thanks for your answer, minergate only has PPLNS for ethereum, and my balance is still on 0.0000000 which is weird considering my hashes. 
and I have no bad share so far

Comment: With PPLNS there is an element of ‘luck’. This may be the reason you haven’t seen a payout. However, the more likely reason is that your balance is unconfirmed right now. The higher your miners hashrate the faster they are confirmed by minergates servers. They’ve said that it can range from a couple of minutes to a couple of days to get your balance confirmed :) minergate.com/faq/what-is-unconfirmed-balance

Comment: I see but still, shouldn't I see the unconfirmed balance already? I do see the other ones that I mine

Comment: I’ve just read that with PPLNS, your work gets checked before it even becomes unconfirmed. This can also usually take around 24 hours. Id suggest waiting a little longer to see if you get some unconfirmed balances coming through.